# Vaadin grid Wrong selection

Tags: spring, hibernate, vaadin8

I am writing an Vaadin Application at the moment and I have a problem with the grid selection. If I first edit an item, and delete it afterwards I get an exception.

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.mmm.inventur.data.StockAtLocation with id 252; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.mmm.inventur.data.StockAtLocation with id 252
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:389) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at ...

if i deselect the item first and delete it than, everything works perfectly fine.

The item I edit is an instance of Article it contains multiple StockAtLocation objects, by editing the Article instance I delete a StockAtLocation from the set as well as from the Article object.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Article implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;
@Column(nullable = true, unique = true)
private Long carlaId;
@Column(nullable = true, unique = true)
private Long ean;
@Column(nullable = false, unique = false)
private String name;
private String descr;

@Column(nullable = false)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<StockAtLocation> stocks;


public Article() {
    stocks = new ArrayList<>();
}

public int getCompleteCntStock() {
    int re = 0;
    for (StockAtLocation stock : stocks) {
        re += stock.getCntStock();
    }
    return re;
   }

public int getCompleteOldStock() {
    int re = 0;
    for (StockAtLocation stock : stocks) {
        re += stock.getOldStock();
    }
    return re;
}
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class StockAtLocation implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;

private String stockArea;
private Timestamp lastModify;
private String note;
private int oldStock;
private int cntStock;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = true)
private Device modifiedBy;

@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private StorageLocation storageLocation;

@ManyToOne
private Article article;

}
```

There the exception gets thrown

```
@Service
public class ArticleService {

@Autowired
private ArticleRepository articleRepo;

public void save(final Article article) {
    this.articleRepo.save(article);
}

@Transactional
public void deleteArticle(final Article delete) {
    try {
        this.articleRepo.delete(delete);
    } catch (JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException e) {
        // right here the exception occurs
        throw e;
    }
}
```

the delete Article action

```
this.btnDelete.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
            for (Article selectedItem : articleGrid.getSelectedItems()) {
                    arService.deleteArticle(selectedItem);

            }
            dataProvider.refreshAll();
            articleGrid.deselectAll();
        }
    });
```

the delete StockAtLocation action

```
private Article modified;
@Override
public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
    // store changes in the database
    Set<StockAtLocation> selectedItems = stockGrid.getSelectedItems();
    stockGrid.deselectAll();
    modifyCallBack.deleteStocks(modified, selectedItems);
    // update the grid
    stockGrid.setItems(modified.getStocks());
}
```

the modifyCallBack

```
(deleteFrom, delete) -> {
     if (deleteFrom.getStocks().isEmpty()) {
         return;
     } else if (!deleteFrom.getStocks().removeAll(delete)) {
         throw new Error("removing does not work!");
     }
     stockService.delete(delete);
     dataProvider.refreshItem(deleteFrom);
 });
```

complete stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.mmm.inventur.data.StockAtLocation with id 267; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find                 com.mmm.inventur.data.StockAtLocation with id 267
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:389) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.mmm.inventur.services.$Proxy96.delete(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mmm.inventur.services.ArticleService.deleteArticle(ArticleService.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mmm.inventur.services.ArticleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6725855c.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.mmm.inventur.services.ArticleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4c42894e.deleteArticle(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mmm.inventur.admin.ui.AdminUI$1.buttonClick(AdminUI.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499) ~[vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273) ~[vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237) ~[vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014) ~[vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:384) ~[vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57) ~[vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155) ~[vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116) ~[vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410) [vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274) [vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90) [vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) [vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601) [vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.2.0.jar:8.2.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167) [spring-session-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) [spring-session-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.mmm.inventur.data.StockAtLocation with id 267
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.preserveSnapshot(CollectionType.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:533) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:663) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:401) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete(SimpleJpaRepository.java:168) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:520) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:505) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Include the full stack trace please.

Comment: updated question

Comment: I don't see any mistake for now. I recommend that you try to log all relevant actions (e.g. deletes of entities) and maybe you see why that `StockAtLocation` is missing when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that when you update the item (i.e. after you have edited) the version in database is updated, but the entity in your memory still has the old version, and naturally when you try to delete the item with old version, you get the exception, since it is not found with that version. This is quite common problem when you try to use database entities directly in the UI.

There are couple of approaches. One alternative is to refetch the item after you have updated, so that the inmemory version is the same as in database. Other way is to use middle layer and DTOs instead. In apps with more complex business logic DTOs are a necessity.

Comment: I would assume that the exception would include something about version then. Also I don't see that he declared a version column but I am not that familiar with spring orm jpa.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "middle layer and DTOs" means.

Comment: I update my version in the memory in the modifyCallBack and i checked .size() of the list and it's definitely removed.